# I built an app in flutter but during run time i get A secondary container isnt defined for ColorScheme error

Tags: flutter

Launching lib\main.dart on SOV36 in debug mode...
lib\main.dart:1
: Error: The getter 'secondaryContainer' isn't defined for the class 'ColorScheme'.
../…/pointers/marker_pointer_renderer.dart:631

- 'ColorScheme' is from 'package:flutter/src/material/color_scheme.dart' ('../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/color_scheme.dart').
  package:flutter/…/material/color_scheme.dart:1
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'secondaryContainer'.
  _themeData.colorScheme.secondaryContainer.withOpacity(0.8)
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

: Error: The getter 'secondaryContainer' isn't defined for the class 'ColorScheme'.
../…/pointers/marker_pointer_renderer.dart:642

- 'ColorScheme' is from 'package:flutter/src/material/color_scheme.dart' ('../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/color_scheme.dart').
  package:flutter/…/material/color_scheme.dart:1
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'secondaryContainer'.
  _themeData.colorScheme.secondaryContainer.withOpacity(0.12)
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  : Error: The getter 'secondaryContainer' isn't defined for the class 'ColorScheme'.
  ../…/pointers/range_pointer_renderer.dart:567
- 'ColorScheme' is from 'package:flutter/src/material/color_scheme.dart' ('../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/color_scheme.dart').
  package:flutter/…/material/color_scheme.dart:1
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'secondaryContainer'.
  _themeData.colorScheme.secondaryContainer.withOpacity(0.8)
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  2

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\Users\JONAH\Documents\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1070
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command 'C:\Users\JONAH\Documents\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrade flutter.

```
flutter upgrade
 
flutter pub upgrade
```